# Struts2 prepare method

Tags: java, struts2, action

I'm working on a struts2 application and I have 4 actions related. When I call the first one "EditMagazineAction" y want sometimes to be redirected to "EditBooksAction".
I want this redirection when I'm coming from "ValidateBooksAction". So, I saved in session the value of what I'm coming from, and I call in EditMagazineAction's prepare a method that will check if I want to stay in this action, or change to "EditBooksAction". If all I want to do is redirect to this one ("EditBooksAction"), I don't execute anything else on the prepare method of "EditMagazineAction", but if I wanna stay, I keep going on the prepare.
This is working for me, but I was told that is not "really correct". How bad is this? 
In this project I can't get a real redirection, I can't go directly to "EditBooksAction", so I must go via "EditMagazineAction".

Comment: It can be useful to see your problem in the code, I think

Comment: I don't think prepare() is meant for redirection. Can you not have different string values for the two locations you are talking about and have them redirected to two different methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [redirect action result](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/redirect-action-result.html) like below

```
<package name="public" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="action1" class="...">
        <result name="redirect1" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">action2</param>
        </result>
        <result name="no_redirect">my.jsp</result>
        <result name="redirect2" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">action3</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

then in your action return `redirect1`, `no_redirect` or `redirect2`.